# Problems with writing/reading int arrays in a file (c)

Tags: c, arrays, file, fwrite, fread

I'm trying to read data from a file, a bunch of ints, two 2d arrays and two 1d arrays, the ints read just fine, but the arrays seem to read the wrong data, I'm not sure where the problem is: the writing, the reading or memory allocation. I'm not getting any compiler errors or crashes, but I can't find the issue. I'd apreciate it if you could point it out.

```
void save(int found, int q, int a, int b, int dir,int **board,int **x_board, int n_players, int *p_ships, int *e_ships,int n_ships, int hor, int ver)
{
    int data[]={found,q,a,b,dir,p_ship_count,e_ship_count,n_players,n_ships,hor,ver};
    FILE *sfp;
    if((sfp = fopen("savegame","w"))==NULL)
            {
                 printf("Failed to open file");
                 exit(0);
            }
    fwrite(data,sizeof(int),sizeof(data),sfp);
    fwrite(p_ships,sizeof(int),sizeof(p_ships),sfp);
    fwrite(e_ships,sizeof(int),sizeof(e_ships),sfp);
    fwrite(board,sizeof(int),sizeof(board),sfp);
    fwrite(x_board,sizeof(int),sizeof(x_board),sfp);
    fclose(sfp);
}

int main()
{
...
int **a_board;
int **b_board;
int *p_ships;
int *e_ships;
...
            FILE *rfp;
            if((rfp = fopen("savegame","r"))==NULL)
            {
                 printf("Failed to open file");
                 exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                fread(&found, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&q, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&b, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&dir, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&p_ship_count, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&e_ship_count, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&n_players, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&n_ships, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&hor, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);
                fread(&ver, sizeof(int), 1, rfp);

                p_ships=(int*)calloc(4*n_ships,sizeof(int));
                e_ships=(int*)calloc(4*n_ships,sizeof(int));
                fread(p_ships,sizeof(int),n_ships*4,rfp);
                fread(e_ships,sizeof(int),n_ships*4,rfp);

                a_board = (int**)calloc(hor+2,sizeof(int*));
                for(i=0;i<hor+2;++i)
                {
                    a_board[i]=(int*)calloc(ver+2,sizeof(int));
                }
                b_board = (int**)calloc(hor+2,sizeof(int*));
                for(i=0;i<hor+2;++i)
                {
                    b_board[i]=(int*)calloc(ver+2,sizeof(int));
                }
                if(n_players==1 || n_players==0)
                {
                    fread(*b_board,sizeof(int),(hor+2)*(ver+2),rfp);
                    fread(*a_board,sizeof(int),(hor+2)*(ver+2),rfp);
                }
                if(n_players==2)
                {
                    fread(*a_board,sizeof(int),(hor+2)*(ver+2),rfp);
                    fread(*b_board,sizeof(int),(hor+2)*(ver+2),rfp);
                }

                fclose(rfp);
            }
```

Comment: `fwrite(p_ships,sizeof(int),sizeof(p_ships),sfp);` - this writes either 16, 32 or 64 bytes (depending on your platform). Is that what you intended? Since `sizeof(int)` is the size of an `int` and `sizeof(p_ships)` is the size of a pointer, it will write (size of `int`) * (size of pointer) bytes.

Comment: No, it's supposed to be the number of records in the array, I'll change it now... fwrite(p_ships,sizeof(int),4*n_ships,sfp); - now it crashes :(,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: To make it clear - given `int *p_ships`, `sizeof( p_ships )` returns the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to.  `sizeof()` is a *compile-time* result.

Comment: Please narrow the problem down and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JanKager So now it writes (size of `int`) * 4 * n_ships bytes. fwrite multiplies the middle two arguments, then writes that many bytes.